# Why forge fails with 'GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by forge) in github action CI

Tags: blockchain, ubuntu, foundry, forge

I have faced this issue `forge: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by forge)` in github action ci.

Fortunately, I solved this issue by simply replacing `runs-on: ubuntu-latest` with `runs-on: ubuntu-22.04`

But really want to know why this happened, thanks

Comment: the binary you are running is not compiled for that version of the OS, you need to download the corresponding build for your OS version

Comment: Yeah, thanks @Nulik